# iAds doesn't show up in my released app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

I just submitted an [app to App store](http://itunes.apple.com/hk/app/love-me-not/id418784899?mt=8) and it had been approved by Apple. When I downloaded it from App Store, the iAd didn't show up.

I have network connection, the test ads showed before I submitted it to Apple, I enabled iAd in iTunesConnect. Anything I missed?

Answer (score 3):

The iAd fill rate -- the rate at which you actually get an ad when you request one -- is currently quite small. The actual rate depends on what your app does and who it's marketed to, but having spoken with a lot of developers about it, the average fill rate seems to be about 10%. That means that every 10 times your app requests an ad, it only only receives an ad 1 time. If your app isn't appealing to advertisers, the rate could be even lower.

Basically, Apple doesn't have nearly as many paid ads to send out as there are apps requesting them. It could be that your fill rate will be even lower than 10%.

Many developers solve this problem by using two ad networks, first requesting an iAd, but if they don't receive one, requesting an ad from another network instead, like Admob. These other networks don't pay as well per ad, but they have a much higher fill rate.

Comment: I think the ads can show probably in US only. It doesn't show in my country. Admob is good, isn't it??

Comment: @Samuel I don't have personal experience with AdMob, but I've heard generally good things. Not a lot of money to be made that way, but more than 0.

Answer (score 0):

maybe iAds doesn't display (yet) in your country? It was the same in the Czech republic - tests iAds did work but no way in the released app. Hopefully your app is available worldwide.

Comment: I am sure it doesn't show in my country. I am trying to look for another way instead of iAds..... Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

iAds are currently being served to apps on the U.S., Canada, U.K., Germany, Italy, Spain, France, and Japan App Stores. If you are looking for a solution which supports almost all the countries [AdWhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/) is a good option. It supports also iAds.